# Websocket load test - How to test using external sdk(js file) in Locust/jmeter/nodejs

Tags: node.js, performance, load, load-testing, locust

Websocket load test - How to test using external sdk(js file) in Locust/jmeter/nodejs?

Any suggestions? I am new to this . Want to check for 50K load

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot load test a .js file

   If the .js file provides implementation of a WebSocket server - you need to deploy/launch it somewhere and load test the **deployment**
2. JMeter doesn't support WebSocket protocol out of the box, you will need to install i.e. [JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/), see [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers)  article if you need more comprehensive instructions
3. Locust [doesn't support anything but HTTP protocol](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-other-systems.html) so you will need to use the [plugin as well](https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/socketio_ex.py)
4. Node.js is simply a JavaScript runtime, you either need to write the load tests from scratch or use an existing library like [wsbench](https://github.com/pgriess/wsbench/)